# Create internal links within excelsheet with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I created a excelfile with around 50 worksheets. All information is in the summary in the first worksheet, but for detailed information people can check the source in the worksheet.

I thought it would be nice to have an internal link to the worksheet (people want to know why the sales were down in July 2016 worksheet etc).

But while I seem to be able to create hyperlinks to websites, I just want to make it work in this excel file.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 3):

This question is more about Excel than Python or programming, but you have to use `#`, for example:

```
ws = wb['Sheet1']
cell = ws.cell('A1')
cell.value = '=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!A2")'
```

You can also give the cell a human-friendly display text:

```
cell.value = '=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!A2", "click here")'
```

Will create a link in cell A1 in Sheet1 to cell A2 in Sheet2.

The 2 cells may or may not be on the same sheet.

The `#` tells Excel that this is an hyperlink to a local location, much like `#` is used as an anchor in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function which can be used directly to create hyperlink to a sheet in same excel:

```
def create_hyperlink(ws, at_cell, sheet_name, cell_ref='A1', display_name=None):
    if display_name is None:
        display_name = sheet_name
    to_location = "'{0}'!{1}".format(sheet_name, cell_ref)
    ws[at_cell].hyperlink = Hyperlink(display=display_name, ref=at_cell, location=to_location)
    ws[at_cell].value = display_name
    ws[at_cell].font = Font(u='single', color=colors.BLUE)
```

ws: worksheet where the links will be created
at_cell: cell location where links will be created. e.g. 'A1'
sheet_name: sheet_name of which the link will be created. e.g. 'Sheet1'

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can add local hyperlinks but have to control the location. The specification says this of the location attribute:

> Location within target. If target is a workbook (or this workbook)
>   this shall refer to a sheet and cell or a defined name. Can also be an
>   HTML anchor if target is HTML file.

I think this works by setting target to `None` and `ref` to the cell reference.